# With a ORKLineGraphChartView from ResearchKit is there a way to draw a graph without dots?

Tags: ios, researchkit

With a ORKLineGraphChartView from ResearchKit is there a way to draw a graph without dots?

I would like a single line drawn, without dots at every data point, is there any way to do that with ResearchKit?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope, I ended up using a different library for charts